Shell - Android Flyout custom Hamburger Icon color not changing
I want to use a custom icon and color for the Shell Flyout hamburger menu. I have the following code:
<Shell
...
  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Background}"
  FlyoutBackground="{StaticResource Background}"
  FlyoutBackdrop="{StaticResource PrimaryLighter}"
  FlyoutIcon="{StaticResource HamburgerMenu}"
  Shell.ForegroundColor="Red">

  <Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <FontImageSource x:Key="HamburgerMenu" FontFamily="FontIcons" Glyph="{StaticResource BurgerMenu}" Size="20"
                       Color="{StaticResource Primary}">
      </FontImageSource>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Shell.Resources>

The color of the menu is my static resource - Primary color on iOS just fine (I added the Foreground color Red to test)

But on Android, the color only shows as White. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I am using .NET Maui 8.0.90.
Further, I cannot change the color of the back button when navigating to a page either. Works fine in iOS, but stays white in Android.
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyPage.Views.Info.MyPage"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Background}"
             Title="MyPage">

  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <FontImageSource x:Key="BackButton" FontFamily="FontIcons"
                       Glyph="{StaticResource LeftArrow}"
                       Size="20"
                       Color="{StaticResource Primary}"></FontImageSource>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior IconOverride="{StaticResource BackButton}"></BackButtonBehavior>
  </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>


I reproduced your issue and noticed that github has mentioned such an  issue, and the technical team will help you solve the problem, please stay tuned.
